# Using one observable as a clock to test the other for timeout

Tags: c#, system.reactive

The declaration for what I want to do looks like this:

```
// Checks input source for timeouts, based on the number of elements received 
// from clock since the last one received from source. 
// The two selectors are used to generate output elements.
public static IObservable<R> TimeoutDetector<T1,T2,R>(
        this IObservable<T1> source, 
        IObservable<T2> clock, 
        int countForTimeout,
        Func<R> timedOutSelector, 
        Func<T1, R> okSelector)
```

Marble diagrams are difficult in ascii, but here goes:

```
source --o---o--o-o----o-------------------o---
clock  ----x---x---x---x---x---x---x---x---x---
output --^---^--^-^----^-----------!-------^---
```

I've tried looking for existing `Observable` functions which can combine `source` and `clock` in a way that I can use, but most of the combination functions rely on receiving 'one of each' (`And`, `Zip`), or they re-return the 'previous' value from the 'missing' one (`CombineLatest`), or they're just too far from what I need (`Amb`, `GroupJoin`, `Join`, `Merge`, `SelectMany`, `Timeout`). `Sample` looks close, but I don't want to limit source throughput to the clock rate.

So now I'm stuck trying to fill in the big gap here:

```
return new AnonymousObservable<R>(observer =>
{
    //One observer, two observables??
});
```

Sorry, the 'what have you tried' section is a bit weak here: let's say that I've tried thinking about it! I'm not asking for the full implementation, just:

- Is there a built-in function which could help me which I've missed?
- How do I go about building a lambda-based observer which subscribes to two observables?

Comment: For future readers; In your question I assume your marble diagram is the result of passing  3 for `countForTimeout` parameter?

Comment: @Lee, yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know you weren't asking for the full implementation, but I think this is a solution:

```
public static IObservable<TR> TimeoutDetector<T1, T2, TR>(
    this IObservable<T1> source,
    IObservable<T2> clock,
    int countForTimeout,
    Func<TR> timedOutSelector,
    Func<T1, TR> okSelector)
{
    return source
        .Select(i => clock.Take(countForTimeout).LastAsync())
        .Switch().Select(_ => timedOutSelector())
        .Merge(source.Select(okSelector));
}
```

It works as follows - I notice that your output is the source projected by the okSelector, merged with the timeout events. So I concentrate on producing the timeout events, because the rest is easy.

The idea is to create a countdown everytime the source emits, and decrement this countdown on each clock pulse. We abort the countdown if the source emits, otherwise when the countdown reaches 0 we produce a timedOut events.

Breaking it down:

1. Project each source element into a stream that takes the first `countForTimeout` elements - note the clockstream must be a "hot" observable, because we subscribe to it on every countDown event. It's quite normal for a clock stream to be hot. If this ever gets an event, we timed out.
2. `Switch` will throw away all but the latest countdown stream.
3. Use `Select` to project to the timedOut event.
4. Now just merge in the source events.

Here is the unit test I used, designed to closely resemble your marble diagram (nuget rx-testing & nunit for necessary libraries to compile):

```
    [Test]
    public void AKindOfTimeoutTest()
    {
        var scheduler = new TestScheduler();

        var clockStream = scheduler.CreateHotObservable(
            OnNext(100, Unit.Default),
            OnNext(200, Unit.Default),
            OnNext(300, Unit.Default),
            OnNext(400, Unit.Default),
            OnNext(500, Unit.Default),
            OnNext(600, Unit.Default),
            OnNext(750, Unit.Default), /* make clock funky! */
            OnNext(800, Unit.Default),
            OnNext(900, Unit.Default));


        var sourceStream = scheduler.CreateColdObservable(
            OnNext(50, 1),
            OnNext(150, 2),
            OnNext(250, 3),
            OnNext(275, 4),
            OnNext(400, 5),
            OnNext(900, 6));


        Func<int> timedOutSelector = () => 0;
        Func<int, int> okSelector = i => i;

        var results = scheduler.CreateObserver<int>();

        sourceStream.TimeoutDetector(clockStream, 3, timedOutSelector, okSelector)
                    .Subscribe(results);

        scheduler.Start();

        results.Messages.AssertEqual(
            OnNext(50, 1),
            OnNext(150, 2),
            OnNext(250, 3),
            OnNext(275, 4),
            OnNext(400, 5),
            OnNext(750, 0),
            OnNext(900, 6));
    }
}
```

To try and answer your specific questions:

- Q. Is there a built-in function which could help me which I've missed? A. Probably Scan is the key.
- Q. How do I go about building a lambda-based observer which subscribes to two observables? A. Not quite sure what you mean by this... there are lots of ways of combining streams, you mentioned a most of them.

Comment: I hate you :) I'd come up with something mildly more... long-winded (which also demonstrates what I mean by subscribing to two observables). Now I've just got to get my head round how you do it...

Comment: I hope you'll still vote for me though, even if you hate me. :)

Comment: If my `source` is also hot, do I risk problems by subscribing to it twice inside your function?

Comment: Certainly not if it is hot, sometimes it's a problem if is cold and you subscribe at different times but expect events to be in sync - but I don't do that here. In the cold case, you can always make it hot/warm with a Publish().RefCount() combo.

Comment: Nice.  I'd add that you can probably reduce a bit of needless churn by using something like `source.Select(_ => clock.Take(countForTimeout).LastAsync())` instead of `startCountdown.Select(i => clock.Scan(...).Where(...).Take(1))`

Comment: There we are, even better!

Comment: Very nice.  Simple and sweet.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the Observable.Create approach I alluded to (same test works):

```
public static IObservable<TR> TimeoutDetector<T1, T2, TR>(
    this IObservable<T1> source,
    IObservable<T2> clock,
    int countForTimeout,
    Func<TR> timedOutSelector,
    Func<T1, TR> okSelector)
{
    return Observable.Create<TR>(observer =>
        {
            var counter = countForTimeout;

            var timeoutSub = clock.Subscribe(_ =>
                {
                    var count = Interlocked.Decrement(ref counter);
                    if (count == 0)
                    {
                        observer.OnNext(timedOutSelector());
                    }
                },
                observer.OnError,
                observer.OnCompleted);

            var sourceSub = source.Subscribe(
                i =>
                {
                    Interlocked.Exchange(ref counter, countForTimeout);
                    observer.OnNext(okSelector(i));
                },
                observer.OnError,
                observer.OnCompleted);

            return new CompositeDisposable(sourceSub, timeoutSub);
        });
}
```

Note that Observable.Create is very helpful about ensuring correct Rx grammar is used (i.e. streams emit OnNext* (OnError | OnCompleted)? - which means I can be somewhat relaxed about sending OnError or OnCompleted at most once.

Comment: Nice, I was wondering about all those seemingly redundant locks and checks in OnError and OnCompleted.

Comment: With I could upvote this again. I just switched back to this implementation because I realised the accepted answer doesn't detect if source *never* fires (and it also does repeated subscribes/unsubscribes to clock, which I try to avoid, though I'm not sure why).

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this, which is rather less pretty than James' answer.

```
public static IObservable<R> TimeoutDetector2<T1, T2, R>(
        this IObservable<T1> source, 
        IObservable<T2> clock, int maxDiff,
        Func<R> timedOutSelector, Func<T1, R> okSelector)
{
    return new AnonymousObservable<R>(observer =>
    {
        int counter = 0;
        object gate = new object();
        bool error = false;
        bool completed = false;
        bool timedOut = false;
        var sourceSubscription = source.Subscribe(
            x =>
            {
                lock(gate)
                {
                    if(!error && !completed) observer.OnNext(okSelector(x));
                    counter = 0;
                    timedOut = false;
                }
            },
            ex =>
            {
                lock(gate)
                {
                    error = true;
                    if(!completed) observer.OnError(ex);
                }
            },
            () =>
            {
                lock(gate)
                {
                    completed = true;
                    if(!error) observer.OnCompleted();
                }
            });
        var clockSubscription = clock.Subscribe(
            x =>
            {
                lock(gate)
                {
                    counter = counter + 1;
                    if(!error && !completed && counter > maxDiff && !timedOut)
                    {
                        timedOut = true;
                        observer.OnNext(timedOutSelector());
                    }
                }
            },
            ex =>
            {
                lock(gate)
                {
                    error = true;
                    if(!completed) observer.OnError(ex);
                }
            },
            () =>
            {
                lock(gate)
                {
                    completed = true;
                    if(!error) observer.OnCompleted();
                }
            });

        //need to return a subscription
        return new CompositeDisposable(sourceSubscription, clockSubscription);
    }).Publish().RefCount(); // prevent subscribers provoking more than one subscription to source and clock
}
```

Comment: Spin this around and use `Observable.Create` rather than creating an AnonymousObservable - it will be a lot easier for you here I think. You can subscribe to whatever you like within a Create and return a funky IDisposable (like CompositeDisposable) from the System.Reactive.Disposables namespace to clean up.

Comment: Hm, maybe I'm not seeing it, but I'm assuming just replacing new `AnonymousObservable<R>` with `Observable.Create<R>` wasn't what you meant...

Comment: No, added an answer with the `Create` approach below. Hopefully you can see it allows the same kind of imperative approach as yours is going for, but it's a lot cleaner to build, and safer to subscribe to multiple times.

Comment: It is no longer 'below' :)

Comment: I *always* do that. Gah! See other answer 'around here somewhere'! :)

Comment: Anytime I see locks used with Rx code, I think, "that's probably not the best way".  It's just usually not necessary and is good indication to me to go back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 0):

Of course this is an old question. I've been looking for something more advanced than `timeoutWith` so that I can *cancel* the timeout logic.

I'm wondering if timeout is pretty much equivalent to:

```
race(throwError('timedout').pipe(delay(10000)), yourObs$)
```

Then of course the 'throwError' shown here would be something that was cancellable.

If you're wondering why - I have some 'steps' that are controlled by an observable chain and I have a timeout. However if one of the steps includes opening a dialog box then I want the timeout cancelled!

Comment: I'm guessing `timeout` maybe didn't exist when you wrote the question. Maybe `race` didn't either!